# Morphism, product, coproduct operator precedence and associativity

Tags: parsing, functional-programming, operators, operator-precedence, category-theory

I am writing a parser that will parse a simple functional toy language.
I'm having tough time with *operator precedence* and *associativity* of **morphism**, **product** and **coproduct** operators.

My toy language looks a *tiny* bit like **Haskell**. Example for context:

```swift
let point: (int, int) = (0, 0)         // product
let either: (int | str) = "hello"      // coproduct
let increment: int -> int = a -> a + 1 // morphism
```

In parsing types, I have a hard time deciding if the binary infix *morphism* operator `->` should be right or left associative. The binary infix *functional composition* operator `.` is right associative if I'm not mistaken; maybe it's the same with this operator too?

Should `int -> int -> int` be parsed as `(int -> int) -> int` or `int -> (int -> int)`?

What is the precedence of this operator in relation with the binary infix *product* and *coproduct* operators (`,`, `|`)?

Right now I have the following priorities (from highest to lowest):

- *morphism*
- *product*
- *coproduct*

This means that in absence of round grouping parenthesis `(...)` the language behaves as follows:

The *product* `str, int -> int, str` gets parsed as `str, (int -> int), str`.
The *coproduct* `int | str -> int | str` has the same effect `int | (str -> int) | str`.
And `str, int -> int | int` gets parsed as `(str, (int -> int) | int)`.

Is that correct or am I doing something wrong?

**Reasons why this is a valid question**

> I apologise but I'm avoiding getting flagged when this is a good question because:

1. I could not find resources that explain how these three operators are related to each other, in which way, precedence and associativity.
2. I can't split the question in smaller questions because a change in the general behaviour of one of those things will affect the others significantly.
3. This is a programming related question since it is about abstract syntax tree generation of a programming language.
4. I haven't found similar questions regarding these operators in here (maybe I'm using the wrong keywords).
5. Other people might stumble upon the same problem when making a parser.
6. It doesn't look like it's opinion based to me.

So please consider leaving a comment to tell me how I should improve the question.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? Operator precedence and associativity is a property of the programming language. Since you are the designer of the programming language, you can make the precedence and associativity whatever you want.

Comment: There is a proper way to do it. If I use a convention that nobody is using it will result in a garbage language. So I want to know if I'm doing it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good reason for associativity rules in Haskell. They follow the idea of the currying adjunction. A function of two arguments is isomorphic to a function returning a function. So `(a, b) -> c` is curried to `a -> (b -> c)`. This is why `a->b->c` is interpreted as a function returning a function and not `(a->b)->c`, which would be a function taking a function as an argument. Conversely, for function application we parse `f g h` as `f` taking two arguments `f` and `g`. So function application is left associative, `(f g) h`: `f` acting on `g` produces a function that subsequently acts on `h`. As for products and coproducts, they are just treated like multiplication and addition with the usual precedence rules. Incidentally, `a->b` corresponds to the exponential `b` to the power of `a`, which also makes sense as far as associativity goes.

Comment: I just started reading your book, "Category Theory for Programmers" it is very well written and I believe it will help me become a much better programmer.